# Attach additional data to angular component

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have several **MatTable** components that are generated dynamically (by *ngFor):

```
<div *ngFor="....">
  <table mat-table [attr.data-table-id]="someId" >
    ....
  </table>
  .....
</div>
```

now, in class file of component, i want to find a specific MatTable reference.
i've defined a property in component class:

```
@ViewChildren(MatTable) tables: QueryList<MatTable>;
```

now, i have a reference to all MatTables. but i want find a specific MatTable, for example a MatTable with specific attribute (e.g. data-table-id = 12).
how can i access to coresponding DomElement of each MatTable?
if i can get a reference to corresponding DomElement of a component, i can read attributes of that element and find my desired Component (MatTable).

Answer (score 1):

You can use a basic HTML id tag, and access it this way:

```
  <table mat-table id="myId" [attr.data-table-id]="someId" >
    ....
  </table>
```

In the component :

```
@ViewChildren(MatTable, {read: ElementRef}) public tables: QueryList<ElementRef>;

let theTableIWant: ElementRef = this.tables.find((el: ElementRef) => el.nativeElement.id === myId);
```

Comment: i have several tables and in my component class, i have a collection that reference those tables:

          @ViewChildren(MatTable) tables: QueryList<MatTable>;      

i want find a specific MatTable in the "tabels" list. i set table attributes, so i can find them later. but, i have a reference to MatTable component, and not DomElement.

Comment: You can write `@ViewChildren(MatTable, {read: ElementRef}) public tables: QueryList<ElementRef>` to reference the dom associated to your MatTable

Comment: thanks, but after finding desired ElementRef, how can i find its corresponding MatTable? my main problem is finding a specific MatTable by its DOM attributes.
in my template, i wanted separate each MatTable, i set data-table-id attribute of <table> tag. is there any solution that i can distinguish my MatTables in template and find one of them later (by a criteria) in component class file?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `filter` method of the QueryList object:

```
let table = tables.filter(elRef => elRef.nativeElement.dataset.tableId === 12)[0];

if (table !== undefined) {
  // your logic
}
```